# Collect all specific comments inside code in a table

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

Suppose I have a logger function, and I called it all over my code. My logs usually show the probability of the existence of a problem or a bug. More actions and investigations needed to confirm the problem or bug. For example, maintainer or tester should grab the input, open it in an editor, and if a specific string is inside the input, The problem or bug is confirmed.

I want to document the procedure of confirming the bug in a comment above of the log function in code. I also want to extract all of these kinds of comments and create, say an HTML table from them. So I can give that table to the tester or maintainer to find correct bugs for me.

I show it in a simple code. I know it's silly, but does the job:

```
std::ifstream t("file.txt");
std::string input;
// Read the whole file into input string

// DIAGNOSTICS COMMENT
// NOHELLO_BUG
// Diagnostics steps: 1.Open input file file.txt 2. Search hello inside the file, if hello exists inside the file, there should be a bug, send file.txt to the developer!
if (input.find("hello") == std::string::npos)
{
   logger::log("hello not found inside input file!");
   return false;
}
```

Is there any command in Doxygen for this purpose, although Any other solution is welcome too. The most obvious way is to write that table by myself, But maintaining that table will be a disaster too.

Comment: I am not *exactly* sure what you are trying to do but some code editors have a feature that scans your code for specific comment patterns left by developers and presents them as a table which links back to the code. Common ones are `// TODO: fix this` or `// BUG: freezes in this loop sometimes` etc... It that the sort of thing you mean?

Comment: @Galik Yeah, some kind of user-defined types, like what albert said in his answer, furthermore, I want to extract them automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doxygen contains a.o. the commands `\todo`, `\bug`

From the documentation:

- https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdtodo

> \todo { paragraph describing what is to be done }
>
> Starts a paragraph where a TODO item is described. The description will also add an item to a separate TODO list. The two instances of the description will be cross-referenced. Each item in the TODO list will be preceded by a header that indicates the origin of the item.

- \bug https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdbug:

> \bug { bug description }
>
> Starts a paragraph where one or more bugs may be reported. The paragraph will be indented. The text of the paragraph has no special internal structure. All visual enhancement commands may be used inside the paragraph. Multiple adjacent \bug commands will be joined into a single paragraph. Each bug description will start on a new line. Alternatively, one \bug command may mention several bugs.

Furthermore doxygen contains the command `\xreflist` with which you can define your own lists.

Small excerpt from the documentation (https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdxrefitem):

> \xrefitem  "(heading)" "(list title)" { text }
>
> This command is a generalization of commands such as \todo and \bug. It can be used to create user-defined text sections which are automatically cross-referenced between the place of occurrence and a related page, which will be generated. On the related page all sections of the same type will be collected.
>
> The first argument  is an identifier uniquely representing the type of the section. The second argument is a quoted string representing the heading of the section under which text passed as the fourth argument is put. The third argument (list title) is used as the title for the related page containing all items with the same key. The keys "todo", "test", "bug" and "deprecated" are predefined.

Comment: Thank man, If I can extract all of my own \xrefitems, It is exactly what I'm looking for. Let me test it and inform you.